# Dynamic image and media queries - is there a way to use both at the same time?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

While you can mostly get away with simply resizing a background image to fit a hole, there are occasions when it just doesn't work - for instance, where the primary image topic is in the wrong position or out of shot completely, leaving a confusing image.

Normally, in this case I simply create another version - perhaps a portrait version as well as a landscape version, then use media queries to serve the correct image.

This works okay when you're just dealing with a single image.

Similarly when I have a dynamic image (multiple pages using the same layout template), I can add the image url dynamically as a background image or to an image element. (I use Asp.Net to add the attribute)

However, I now need to be able to combine the two things together - a different background image for each page, with potentially more than one version of the image depending on the screen size.

So, because the image is dynamic, the code sits inline in the html rather than a stylesheet.

But how do I show an alternative using media queries?

At the minute, I can't think of a way of combining both requirements.

Any ideas appreciated.